# Probability measure associated with conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose I define the conditional expectation of a random variable $X$ with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ denoted $E[X|\mathcal{M}]$ on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

Is there a natural associated probability measure on $\mathcal{M}$ that goes along with $E[X|\mathcal{M}]$? This would be probability measure which in some sense contains the information only contained in $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't really measures which are thought of as containing information, but rather $\sigma$-algebras. Indeed, probability measures are a somewhat disjoint concept from the concept of a $\sigma$-algebra.

For any random variable, the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X)$ generated by the events $[X\in E]$ for $E\subset\mathbb R$ open is a natural $\sigma$-algebra associated to the r.v. $X$ in the sense that $\sigma(X)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ such that $X$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable. Then, if you have any probability measure $P$ on $\Omega$, you are free to consider the restricted probability space $(\Omega,\sigma(X),P|_{\sigma(X)})$. The discussion of this paragraph applies to r.v.'s of the form $E[X\mid\mathcal F]$.

---

$\sigma$-algebras are indeed very detailed objects, so it can be hard to see the forest for the trees when it comes to the "containing information" perspective. The most basic way to see it is to consider a r.v. $X$ that takes only finitely many values $a_1,\dots,a_n$. Then all the information we could want to know about $X$ is contained in the events $[X=a_1],\dots,[X=a_n]$ since knowing which of these level sets our sample $\omega\in\Omega$ is in tells us everything about $X$ from the perspective of probability. There are more complicated events we can fashion from these $n$ events like $[X\in\{a_1,a_2,a_5\}]$, but all of these events are captured by the idea of forming the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the events $[X=a_1],\dots,[X=a_n]$.

In a more complicated situation, we may be considering several r.v.s $X_1,\dots,X_n$, or even a continuum of r.v.s like $(X_t)_{t\in[a,b]}$ (as in the study of continuous-time random processes). The basic elements to keep in mind are always the level sets $[X < r]$, $r\in\mathbb R$, as these are essentially the simplest events telling us fundamental information about the variables $X$. Then when we want to ensure we are capturing all the detailed events or "information" about $X$, we pass to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the level-set events $[X<r]$, $r\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: When we say the $\sigma$-algebra corresponding knowledge of information, does this mean that if I knew what all the sets in my $\sigma$-algebra were, I could know what kind of outcomes I were to see? Could you help me understand this? The $\sigma$-algebra feels really complicated and messy

Comment: @SamKirkiles: I added some discussion of the idea that $\sigma$-algebras correspond to "information". I think if you pick up the study random processes, this idea will become more natural, but a good base point to keep in mind is the fundamental idea that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a r.v. $X$ is the one generated by the level-set events $[X<r]$, $r\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sam: For a simple case, take rolling a dice three times.  The $\sigma$ algebra contains every possible event that could be asked about the 3 random variables, $X_i$, which are the three outcomes of the dice. An intersection of three events say: even and less than 5 on the first outcome, a 4 on the second outcome and odd on the third outcome. Obviously, even in this relatively simple discrete case of rolling a dice three times, the sigma algebra becomes enormous and contains tons of events. In fact, it contains every single event that you could possibly ask about.